# Converting MongoDB query to PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

First query works when I run at Robomongo. However, am having trouble converting it to PHP.

I've included the updated version, please let me know if I miss anything.

**This works (MongoDB query)**

```
db.statusNew.find(
    {_id: ObjectId("123")}, 
    {
        statuses: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id : 321
        }}
    }
).limit(1)
```

**This doesn't work (translated to PHP)**

```
$queryOri = array(
  (_id: new MongoId($id)),
  (
      statuses: (
      $elemMatch: (
          id : $tweetID['id']
      ))
  )
);

$query = $collection.find($queryOri).limit(1);
```

**Updated!**

```
$collection -> find(
    array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),
    array(
        'statuses' => array(
            $elemMatch: (
                id: $tweetID['id']
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**Array looks like this :**

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 123
    )

    [statuses] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [id] => 321
            [text] => Tweet no 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
            [id] => 322
            [text] => Tweet no 2
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
            [id] => 323
            [text] => Tweet no 3
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$collection->find(
    array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),
    array(
        'statuses' => array(
            '$elemMatch' => array(
                'id'=>$tweetID['id']
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You have to use colons(:) instead of assingment(=>). In mongodb every curly brackets will considers in php as array only.Hope you got this answer.